# "The Love Letter Mystery" - storing and comparison of strings

Tags: c, strings, programming-challenge, palindrome

The problem goes like this.

> Change the strings provided by user to form palindromes. To do this, 2
> rules are:
>
> (a) Reduce the value of a letter, e.g. Change 'd' to 'c',
> but cannot change 'c' to 'd'.
>
> (b) In order to form a palindrome, you
> can repeatedly reduce the value of a letter until the letter becomes
> 'a'. Once a letter has been changed to 'a', it can no longer be
> changed.
>
> Each reduction in the value of any letter is counted as a single
> operation. Find the minimum number of operations required to convert a
> given string into a palindrome.

This is a HackerRank problem: [the-love-letter-mystery](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery#!)

While I was solving it, I made a lot of mistakes. I was using `char *str[n]` and `gets()` to input the string. I thought it would work, but I realised after long time that I am not actually allocating any space at all. Later I came up with 2-d array `char[n][1000]` for storing the strings and `scanf` seemed to work for me.

Here is my solution:

```
int main() {


    int i, n, len, pos, ops, end;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char str[n][10000];
    char a,b;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        len = strlen(str[i]);
        pos = 0;
        end = len - 1;
        ops = 0;
        while ( pos < end) {
               a = str[i][pos];
               b = str[i][end];
               if ( a != b ) {
                   if ( b > a ) 
                       ops = ops + (b -a);
                   else 
                       ops = ops + (a -b); 
               }
               pos++;
               end--;    
        }
        printf("%d\n", ops);
    }

return 0;
}
```

This works perfectly. I also have to assume in the program that the strings can be of max length 1000 as that is one of the constraint.

How can I improve this solution without making it too complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As Yann already said,) There is probably no room to improve your algorithm.
But the implementation can be cleaned-up a little.

You don't have to store all input strings in an array. You can read a string,
compute the number of operations and print the result, then proceed to the next
string. So only one string buffer is needed. The maximal string length should be
defined as a constant.

```
if ( a != b ) {
   if ( b > a ) 
       ops = ops + (b -a);
   else 
       ops = ops + (a -b); 
}
```

can be simplified to

```
ops += abs(a - b);
```

and then you don't need temporary `char` variables at all:

```
ops += abs(str[pos] - str[end]);
```

I would move the computation part for a single string to a separate function.
That makes it easier to add test cases and makes the main function shorter
and more clear.

Putting it all together:

```
static int palindromeOps(const char *str)
{
    int pos = 0;
    int end = strlen(str) - 1;
    int ops = 0;
    while (pos < end) {
        ops += abs(str[pos] - str[end]);
        pos++;
        end--;
    }
    return ops;
}

const int MAXSTRINGLENGTH = 10000;

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[MAXSTRINGLENGTH];

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", str);
        int ops = palindromeOps(str);
        printf("%d\n", ops);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Remark:* Note that generally, reading a string with `scanf("%s", str)`
is not safe and can cause a
buffer overflow. This might not be relevant here if we "trust" the input
from the programming challenge. As an alternative, you can use something like
`scanf("%*s", sizeof(str), str)` or `fgets()`.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time and answering this. However would like if you could use the fgets only in the code instead of showing with scanf.

Comment: @kingsdeb: You are welcome. I can update the answer later.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this seems pretty good. There might be a faster way to do it, but it's not coming to mind.

I'd maybe not declare your `int i` that early on, and use the standard format instead, as that's what's expected.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

As well as this, I'd give `n` a more descriptive name, such as `num_lines` or something similar. The same can be said for the other variables. `ops` and `pos` could give more information about what they're doing.